# Mysql uninstall with MSI installer fails

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql server 5.7 on windows 10.
Start process was failing.
So I tried to uninstall Mysql Server and I am getting :

> error 1723. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A
>   DLL required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact
>   your support personnel or package vendor

How can I remove Mysql manually in order to re install it?

Comment: How did you try to uninstall it?

Comment: What did you use to install MySQL in the first place?

Comment: I used the MSI installer  (5.7.19). I first tried to uninstall from the MSI installer, then from Configuration Panel of Windows. But got the same error. I am trying to uninstall it manually. But that seems quite hard to do.